# Yellow Dog Democrat in modern usage?

Tags: united-states, democratic-party

I am curious about the usage of the word "yellow dog Democrat". I read that it is a word that means a Democrat that always votes straight ticket and would never even think of voting for a Republican. Is this term still used or has it been retired (or replaced with a different color dog) to describe stubborn Democrats because of its past history in the South?

Its origin is "I would vote for a yellow dog if it were a Democrat".

Comment: It's antiquated. The term "blue dog" for a borderline Democrat is much more common, though perhaps also losing currency.

Comment: @Colin See my answer below for the Google n-gram results. I would have made the same assumptions you had without looking at the data.

Comment: Just an observation, not really an answer. I've rarely heard either term (yellow or blue dog), and I studied this material. Looking at @DonHosek's chart, I suspect the terms arose among pundits during the 90s while the nation was descending into its current partisan divide, but now that we are so deeply polarized everyone *expects* party members to by hyper-partisan, so the special term isn't needed and is falling out of use.

Comment: Yes. It is in modern usage. The phrase is familiar and widely understood and has been for at least 40 years which I as far back as I can recall listening to political discussions.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Graph comparing the prevalence of yellow dog democrat vs blue dog democrat in the period 1900–2020]

I have to admit the first time I ever heard the term "yellow dog Democrat" was during the 1990s when it came up in the context of the "blue dog Democrat" movement of centrist Democrats. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Dog_Coalition). What was interesting to me was to pull up the Google n-gram which showed that until recently, "blue dog Democrat" has been consistently used less than "yellow dog Democrat", that the latter saw an upturn in usage beginning around the Carter administration and both terms have been in decline since the midpoint of the Obama administration.

Comment: counterpoint: https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=US&q=blue%20dog,yellow%20dog

Comment: @Colin Good point. On the other hand, the difference in search results might be a consequence of "yellow dog" being less familiar, but ultimately, who knows? I think there's more hope in discerning the meaning of bird entrails than aggregate Google searches.

Comment: I think including "democrat" in the phrase gives a better [GoogleTrends result](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=US&q=blue%20dog%20democrat,yellow%20dog%20democrat).